# Forum owner taking advantage of your IP address to see your online activities?

Tags: forum

if a forum owner knows your IP address, is there a chance that he might search your IP address and find what other forums on the WWW what you've been posting with your IP address?

Comment: What do you mean 'search your IP address?'

Answer (score 2):

Not unless he has admin access to those other forums. Most forums do not disclose IP addresses of other users publicly.

Depending on your ISP **you may not even have a static address** anyways, so if another user has your IP address there is nothing to worry about, tons of other people have used that address before too and yours will change again regardless.